# Mapbox not starting in a Fragment

Tags: android, mapbox

I was trying the Mapbox in Android, but it is not getting displayed on the android fragment

I get the following error

```
10-29 11:34:25.300 17208-17208/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-29 11:34:25.657 17208-17208/com.example I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
10-29 11:34:25.795 17208-17251/com.example I/mbgl: {Map}[Android]: Not activating as we are not ready
10-29 11:34:25.796 17208-17251/com.example I/mbgl: {Map}[Android]: Not deactivating as we are not ready
10-29 11:34:25.852 17208-17252/com.example D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-29 11:34:25.876 17208-17208/com.example D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: 
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
10-29 11:34:25.950 17208-17252/com.example I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
10-29 11:34:25.957 17208-17252/com.example I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-29 11:34:25.985 17208-17252/com.example D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-29 11:34:26.071 17208-17208/com.example E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-29 11:34:26.071 17208-17208/com.example E/mbgl: {Main}[OpenGL]: eglCreateWindowSurface() returned error 12296
10-29 11:34:26.072 17208-17208/com.example A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 17208 (.materialdesign)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MapBoxFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FriendsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MessagesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/altMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapbox:accessToken="sk.sdfsdf......."/>

</FrameLayout>
```

MapboxFragment.java

```
public class MapBoxFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView = null;

    View convertView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

        mapView = (MapView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.altMapView);
        mapView.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(new LatLng(0, 0));

        // Show user location (purposely not in follow mode)
        mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

When using the same layout within the Activity it is working.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Did you find a way to solve it?

Answer (score 13):

I was got this exact problem when I updated my Mapbox SDK for android. I solved it by adding `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` after I initialzed the `MapView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: It work with null instead of savedInstanceState if you use the mapView in an adapter.